# Перешел на https - не запускается flash на сайте

Tags: html5, flash, https

На моем блоге есть страницы с вебкамерами. Вот одна из них: [с камерами Питера](https://lglive.ru/kontakty/veb-kamery-goroda-sankt-peterburga/).

После перехода на *https* вебкамеры перестали работать. То есть они работают, но вместо окошка с плеером отображается пустое место.

Никак не могу понять, что случилось.

Погуглив, нашел такое мнение, что Гугл запретил использовать *flash* на сайтах, а вместо него предлагает использовать *html5*. Как мне быть?

Answer (score 2):

Типичный запрет смешанного контента. Замените ваши ссылки вида

```
http://vpiter.com/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.18.swf
```

на

```
https://vpiter.com/swf/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.18.swf
```

Если сайт переведен на https, то все отображаемые на странице элементы должны загружаться через https.

Comment: А лучше, конечно, от Flash отказаться, как это сделали многие.